# Infinite group G is polycyclic then subgroup of fitting is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a infinite  polycyclic group i.e soluble and satisfy max. Show that  the subgroup of fitting of G is  nilpotent.
he subgroup of fitting of G is subgroup of G generated by normal nilpotent subgroup of G.

Comment: the subgroup of generated by normal nilpotent subgroup

Comment: This is a question in advanced group theory. I'd expect some real effort/work has already been done here.

Comment: $$Fit(G):=\langle\; N\lhd G\;:\;\;N\;\;\text{is nilpotent}\;\rangle$$

Comment: Do you know how to show this when there are only finitely many normal nilpotent subgroups?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft BY using maximal subgroup OF G AND show that this maximal subgroup is G?

Comment: Let me rephrase. Do you know how to show this when $G$ is finite?

Comment: YES i know because it is staisfy max-n

Comment: What do you mean by that? I mean do you know how this argument goes when $G$ is finite (the idea is the see that one can do something similar here).

Comment: max-n  i.e  maximal condition on normal subgroups .

Comment: I know how to do this argument  when G is finite

Comment: Then let $N_i$ for $i\in I$ be the normal nilpotent subgroups of $G$ (let's say that $I$ contains the natural numbers for simplicity). Consider the chain $N_1\leq N_1N_2\leq \cdots$

Comment: You just need to know that the subgroup generated by finitely many normal nilpotent subgroups is nilpotent.

Comment: yes that what i am trying to do

Comment: @amel If $\;G\;$ is polycyclic (or even only *virtually* polycyclic), take the set $\;\{ N\lhd G\;:\;\;N\;\text{is nilpotent} \}\;$ . This set has a maximal element And it isn't empty, of course).

Comment: @Timbuc it is clear now using the set has a maximal element And it isn't empty because it contain identity element

Comment: @Timbuc i have work about BIGENETIC PROPERTIES OF FINITELY GENERATED HYPER-(ABELIAN-BY-FINITE)GROUPS Can you help me?

Comment: @amel I can try. Post your question in the site, but I've to tell you there's people with better knowledge of group thery than myself, e.g. Derek Holt. So do not direct your question to me but just post it as you did this question.

Comment: @amel I'd rather won't as I am doing my own research (well,I'm still a beginner in graduate school but I'm about to begin with research) and I don't want to make a compromise I cannot fulfill. Either copy the article into a link and write the link here, and I will try to read some of it (no swear!), or else post new question(s) about special, definite doubts you have in that article.